# Why do Gunicorn sync workers hang when spawning threads?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have a Python log handler that [spawns a new thread for each log entry](https://github.com/2degrees/logentries-handler/blob/a971049ce7c05d57177abd955f14043c92afbf91/logentries_handler.py#L57), and within the new thread the log is sent to another server. However, I'm finding that the request times out intermittently. If I disable the handler, the problem goes away.

I have tried other WSGI servers (WSGIUtils, WSGIRef) and I cannot reproduce this issue.

Any ideas?

I'm running Gunicorn 19.3 with sync workers and Django 1.6 on Debian.

Comment: Is this logging during the request cycle? Are you sure you are not blocking on the thread when it is waiting to push the log out to the socket ?

Comment: I'm not sure how the new thread could interfere with gunicorn but creating a new thread per log message is pretty expensive. Try to create a queue instead and a worker thread which processes log entries in the queue. The rest of the logging system can then push into the queue which should be very fast.

Comment: @andrefsp: Yes, and the function in the thread could well take too long to complete, but why would this affect the time it takes to complete a request?

Comment: @AaronDigulla I agree it'd be more expensive, but we did it because it'd require less code (compared to having a queue) and the performance tax wasn't significant in the testing. However, how could this cause the problem with the workers taking too long to respond to a request?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another case of GIL - Global Interpreter Lock. Assume this happens:

- Request comes in
- Worker starts
- Worker logs -> thread is started
- Worker is done
- Response is sent
- Thread logs event

Looks good, right. But what if the thread does its work faster? Then you get:

- Request comes in
- Worker starts
- Worker logs -> thread is started
- Worker is done
- Thread logs event
- Response is sent

and depending on which locks the thread holds or which OS functions it invokes, the thread might not release the GIL for some time which would block the worker or at least prevent the response from being delivered completely.

When looking at the code, I see that you're creating an SSL connection for each log message. SSL is very, very, **very** expensive. Don't do that. Instead, create a worker thread which opens the SSL socket once and keeps it open. The python library should release the GIL when you write to the socket so other code can work. But I'm not sure whether Python releases the lock when you open a socket.

Comment: Thanks! But can't the same issue arise with a single, long-running thread that uses a queue? Since you say that "depending on which locks the thread holds or which OS functions it invokes, the thread might not release the GIL for some time". Presumably the same can happen with a long-running thread, right?

Comment: I also forgot to ask: If it's the GIL, why doesn't this happen with other WSGI servers? I've tried WSGIUtils and WSGIRef, and there's no problem with them.

Comment: Can you try to create the SSL connection only once? If that works, I have an idea why it's a problem.